# What's the reason for different positions of the indefinite article "a" in these sentences?

Tags: word-order, indefinite-article

> He is a very smart guy.

> He is such a smart guy.

> He is so smart a guy.

<sub>Examples from the *Hound of the Baskervilles* [Ch 1](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2852/2852-h/2852-h.htm#linklink2HCH0001) "You interest me very much, Mr. Holmes. I had hardly expected *so dolichocephalic a skull* or such well-marked supra-orbital development.")  or [Ch 2](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2852/2852-h/2852-h.htm#linklink2HCH0002) "It chanced that this Hugo came to love (if, indeed, *so dark a passion* may be known under *so bright a name*) the daughter of a yeoman who held lands near the Baskerville estate."</sub>

> He is quite a smart guy.
> Alternative:He is **a quite** smart guy.

> He is a nice guy.
> Alternative:He is **nice a** guy.

Why these sentences have position for the indefinite article varying?

Can the alternatives (as) suggested by me also be used?

Comment: What is the source of the examples?  The third one seems odd, but may work in context.

Comment: The 3rd kind of sentence is very common in the Hound of the Baskervilles.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh I think it's old-fashioned English.

Comment: I've edited to add a couple of examples from Conan Doyle. I think they illustrate the usage better. It is very important to provide this kind of link or citation! On its own "He is so smart a guy." is not English, but it can be part of a longer sentence. "If so smart a guy may be called a fool then I too am a fool!".

Answer (score 1):

The firsts two examples show the same form:

> He is **a** very **smart** guy.
>
> He is such **a smart** guy.

The difference between these two is the intensifier *very* which adds to the intensity of the word "smart".

You can also put the indefinite article after the adjective in English, however it is not used that often and that may be why you don't recognise it:

> He is so **smart a** guy

This has a very subtle change in meaning. Instead of simply stating he is a guy who is smart, it is saying that "Out of all guys, he is so smart". This does not make sense as a standalone comment however; it is often used as justification for something else: "He is *so smart a guy* that they can't even teach him."

With regards to your suggested sentences:

> He is a quite smart guy.

This still follows the same format of *a smart guy*, but you have moved the word "quite". It is correct but not common.

> He is nice a guy.

This is not correct.

Comment: Do you want to explain the downvote so I can improve my answer?

Comment: Not my DV but "He is so smart a guy." and "It's very good a game." are ungrammatical, and it does not answer the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, though, I would've downvoted. 'a' is an indefinite article and 'very' as an intensifier (because it intensifies, as you said). Btw, are you saying 'nice a guy' is a correct construction? It strikes me as odd.

Comment: @WeatherVane "He's so smart a guy that they don't need anyone else" makes sense to me.

Comment: That is not what you wrote.

Comment: @WeatherVane I know, but "he is so smart a guy" is correct

Comment: @AricFowler 'so smart a guy' is idiomatic because of the word 'so'. *Nice a person* is odd, at least to me.

Comment: Both "so smart a guy" and "so nice a person" only make sense when followed by more of the sentence (the excuse for word re-ordering), but not as stand-alone remarks.

Comment: @WeatherVane I see your point. I'll add that in.